# Can't read objects properties from file written by using object output stream

Tags: java

I am trying to read a file which I myself write using object output stream ,this is how I write it:

```
        try
        {
            fout = new FileOutputStream("VehicleOrders.dat");   
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);  

            for(vehicle v:orderList)       ///Travesing to array collection  of vehicles and typecasting to repective child object then calling individual methods                
              {
              oos.writeObject(v);           //Here I have checked 'v' isproperly initialized and has the required properties assigned too
              }

         }
```

After this it writes into the file, some data,I bieleve the details  of 'v'

Then I tried to read the same file like this:

```
fin = new FileInputStream("VehicleOrders.dat");  //this is the same  file,
               ois = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
               vehicle readInstance=null;
               while (orderCount>0)   //here order count is number of objects in the file kind of meta data
               {
                  readInstance = (vehicle)ois.readObject();  //here 'readInstance' object is set to right object class i.e car but all the properties for some reason are set to null!!!!
                  if(readInstance != null)
                  {
                     orderList.add(readInstance);   //read instance is not null ,it has car object but its values are set to zero :(
                  } 
                  orderCount--;   
               }   
               ois.close();   





   //as u see I can't read it properly,I believe this is because one of these reasons or other:
Maybe the file is not written properly,but I check object v before writing,it is proper
maybe because it has to do some thing with the class it uses and its constructors i.e vehicle and Car which extends vehicle
May be some other reason I am not aware of
```

Comment: I found that the reading is not the problem but the writing I am modifying my question wait

Comment: Looks okay to me.  You should step through the debugger such as setting a breakpoint right after setColor() and see if the color did set properly.

Comment: @Snedden27 why serialization tag? i dont see the use here.

Comment: @Snedden27 Please show us the Car Class...

Comment: Before adding it to the list, the attributes are null or are OK ( as you setted)?

Comment: the think it as I found out is that the items get added to the list properly , but when  I read them from the .dat file the always read null.

Comment: You need to close the ObjectOutputStream, but "can't read properly" is not an adequate problem description.

Answer (score -1):

I think you may have done the following mistake:

Suppose your `Car` class is below:

```
class Car{
    private String color;
.......
......
}
```

Than you may have written the setter as below:

```
public void setColor(String color){
    color=color;
}
```

**Here it should be :**

```
public void setColor(String color){
        this.color=color;
    }
```

Comment: This is just guesswork. There is no evidence of such a problem here.

Comment: @EJP just go through the logs oh the changes the question has gone through. In one instance my assumption was looking very valid.